# Handling JSON/Array fields in Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel to create a CRM. I want accounts to be able to be of multiple account_types. In an account types tables there will be an ID and a title, then in the Accounts table I plan to have a column that stores a json object of which types this account is a part of.

I am looking for the proper way to handle this in Laravel with Eloquent to associate these and be able to do something like `$account->types()` and return an array of the account types that the account belongs to, IE

```
array(
    1 => 'Customer',
    3 => 'Vendor'
)
```

and also be able to do something like `Account::where('account_type', 1)->get();` and return all "Customers"

I am currently using MySQL for the database, so arrays are not much of an option.

Comment: could you show your SQL query string

Comment: If you want to use Eloquent features, then just create pivot table and make it m-m relationship (`belongsToMany` on both sides). Then you can call `$account->types` to get all the types.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to do that, I would create a third table specifically for account/type relations instead of a json object in the table. So, hypothetically if your tables were named Account, Types, and Account_Types you could get all of the types for a specific account via something like:

```
Account_Types::select('title')
->where('accountID', '=', $account_id)
->get();
```

Then to get all accounts of a certain type, just join the tables and run a select:

```
Account::join('account_types', 'account_types.accountID', '=', 'account.id')
->join('types', 'types.id', '=', 'account_types.typeID')
->select('account.id as id')
->where('types.id', '=', $type_id)
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Response;

return Response::json(array('1' => 'Customer', '2' => 'Vendor'));
```

[details](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#special-responses)